# get template format string with UrlBuilder

Tags: spring, uri

Is there any way to get url template format from URI or UriBuilder?
ex) `"/{id}?testQuery=test"`

when doing this:

```
uriBuilder
    .path("/{id}")
    .queryParam("testQuery", "test")
    .build(1).toString()
```

and got `"/1?testQuery=test"`.

I tried `.toUriString` instead of `.build`, but it came out as `/%7Bid%7D?testQuery=test`. Similar to what i want, but not exactly.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?